# Compound, multi-valued search quicker than a dumb-dumb loop?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to do a multi-column matchy sort of thing. I don't even know what to call it, so I'm not even sure how to search. "compound match"...?

I have a bunch of "candidate" numbers (each one is a 25-character code) in a worksheet (worksheet called "RPT - Shelf Age"). In a *different* worksheet ("MasterSheet", which BTW, contains thousands or tens of thousands of rows), I want to determine if the following condition exists:

*Is there a row where column D equals CANDIDATE_NUMBER, and column F = "bananas" or "oranges"? (the answer can be the row value in MasterSheet)*

(note: there will be values in column F other than "bananas" or "oranges" and I have to ignore those.)

Now at the moment, I do it a very dumb-dumb way:

```
' Now loop through each of the candidates and hunt for TRANSACTION TYPES that match the ScanID,
' and are either SCHEDULED or DEPLOYED. These are items that ARE NOT STALE. Repair their flags.
  Dim LastRowOfCandidates As Long
  Dim ShelfAgeCounter As Long
  Dim MastersheetTransactionRowIndex As Long
  Dim CandidateScanID As Long
  Dim ItemResolved As Boolean
  LastRowOfCandidates = Worksheets("RPT - Shelf Age").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
   MsgBox ("There are " & LastRowOfCandidates & " rows of complete data in this report." & vbCrLf)
  For ShelfAgeCounter = 3 To LastRowOfCandidates ' cycle through each candidate
    ItemResolved = False
    TargetRow = 2
    MastersheetTransactionRowIndex = Worksheets("RPT - Shelf Age").Cells(ShelfAgeCounter, 1) ' this is the row in which the candidate appears on the MasterSheet
    CandidateScanID = MastersheetTransactionRowIndex = Worksheets("RPT - Shelf Age").Cells(ShelfAgeCounter, 4) ' the ScanID to hunt for
     'Search the MasterSheet for any occurrence of CandidateScanID where the action is SCHEDULE or DEPLOYED
      Do Until Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(TargetRow, 1) = "" Or ItemResolved = True
        If Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(TargetRow, 4) = CandidateScanID And Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(TargetRow, 6) = "Scheduled for Delivery" Then
          'Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(MastersheetTransactionRowIndex, 37) = ""
          ItemResolved = True
        End If
        If Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(TargetRow, 4) = CandidateScanID And Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(TargetRow, 6) = "Equipment Deployed" Then
          Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(MastersheetTransactionRowIndex, 37) = ""
          ItemResolved = True
        End If
        TargetRow = TargetRow + 1
      Loop ' finished looking for a match on MasterSheet
  Next
```

Now, this works, but holy tick-tock, it takes a long time.

Considering that this is Excel and it may have very fast ways of finding data in its own tables, is there a way that *doesn't* require **Max Search Time = Number of CANDIDATES * Number of MasterSheet rows**?

Thank you kindly!

-=-=-=-=-=-=-

Addendum:

This is the entire sub, including an attempt to use AUTOFILTER:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
  Worksheets("RPT - Shelf Age").Rows("3:5000").EntireRow.Delete ' I REALLY hope there aren't more than 5000 stale items!
  Worksheets("RPT - Shelf Age").Range("A3").Activate
  Dim CurrentReportRow As Long
  Dim TargetRow As Long
  CurrentReportRow = 3
  TargetRow = 2
  ' Pull in all the CANDIDATE items from the Master Sheet that have perhaps not yet been reconciled
  ' This is not a full data set because I only need a few values to scrub through Candidates.
    Do Until Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(TargetRow, 1) = ""
      If Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(TargetRow, 37) = 1 Then
        Worksheets("RPT - Shelf Age").Cells(CurrentReportRow, 1) = TargetRow
        Worksheets("RPT - Shelf Age").Cells(CurrentReportRow, 2) = Left(Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(TargetRow, 4), 10)
        Worksheets("RPT - Shelf Age").Cells(CurrentReportRow, 3) = Mid(Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(TargetRow, 4), 12, 11)
        Worksheets("RPT - Shelf Age").Cells(CurrentReportRow, 4) = Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(TargetRow, 4)
        CurrentReportRow = CurrentReportRow + 1
      End If
      TargetRow = TargetRow + 1
    Loop

MsgBox ("Hold up there a sec, hoss!") ' I include this test stop to let me review the table before proceeding.

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsMaster As Worksheet
    Dim wsRPT As Worksheet
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim aCandidateIDs As Variant
    Dim vID As Variant
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsMaster = wb.Worksheets("MasterSheet")
    Set wsRPT = wb.Worksheets("RPT - Shelf Age")
    With wsRPT.Range("D3", wsRPT.Cells(wsRPT.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
        If .Row < 3 Then Exit Sub   ' No data
        If .Cells.Count = 1 Then
            ReDim aCandidateIDs(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
            aCandidateIDs(1, 1) = .Value
        Else
            aCandidateIDs = .Value
        End If
    End With
    With wsMaster.Range("D1:F" & wsMaster.Cells(wsMaster.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row)
        For Each vID In aCandidateIDs
            .AutoFilter 1, vID                                                  'Filter column D for the ID
            .AutoFilter 3, "Scheduled for Delivery", xlOr, "Equipment Deployed" 'Filter column F for the two other strings

             ' Check if there are any results
            On Error Resume Next
            Set rFound = .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1) ' This assumes you only want the first match found.  For all matches, leave off the .Cells(1)
            On Error GoTo 0
            .AutoFilter 'Remove the filter
            If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                ' Found a match, do something with it here
                ' Because we only returned the first match, no need to iterate over rFound because it will only be 1 cell
                MsgBox "Candidate ID: " & vID & Chr(10) & "Match found on MasterSheet at row: " & rFound.Row
            End If
        Next vID
    End With

    ' Now loop through each of the candidates and hunt for TRANSACTION TYPES that match the ScanID,
    ' and are either SCHEDULED or DEPLOYED. These are items that ARE NOT STALE. Repair their flags.
      'Dim LastRowOfCandidates As Long
      'Dim ShelfAgeCounter As Long
      'Dim MastersheetTransactionRowIndex As Long
      'Dim CandidateScanID As Long
      'Dim ItemResolved As Boolean
      'LastRowOfCandidates = Worksheets("RPT - Shelf Age").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
      ' MsgBox ("There are " & LastRowOfCandidates & " rows of complete data in this report." & vbCrLf)
      'For ShelfAgeCounter = 3 To LastRowOfCandidates ' cycle through each candidate
        'ItemResolved = False
        'TargetRow = 2
        'MastersheetTransactionRowIndex = Worksheets("RPT - Shelf Age").Cells(ShelfAgeCounter, 1) ' this is the row in which the candidate appears on the MasterSheet
        'CandidateScanID = MastersheetTransactionRowIndex = Worksheets("RPT - Shelf Age").Cells(ShelfAgeCounter, 4) ' the ScanID to hunt for
        ' Search the MasterSheet for any occurrence of CandidateScanID where the action is SCHEDULE or DEPLOYED
          'Do Until Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(TargetRow, 1) = "" Or ItemResolved = True
            'If Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(TargetRow, 4) = CandidateScanID And Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(TargetRow, 6) = "Scheduled for Delivery" Then
              'Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(MastersheetTransactionRowIndex, 37) = ""
              'ItemResolved = True
            'End If
            'If Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(TargetRow, 4) = CandidateScanID And Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(TargetRow, 6) = "Equipment Deployed" Then
              'Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(MastersheetTransactionRowIndex, 37) = ""
              'ItemResolved = True
            'End If
            'TargetRow = TargetRow + 1
          'Loop ' finished looking for a match on MasterSheet
      'Next

  ' Empty out this table
    Worksheets("RPT - Shelf Age").Rows("3:5000").EntireRow.Delete ' I REALLY hope there aren't more than 5000 stale items!
    Worksheets("RPT - Shelf Age").Range("A3").Activate
  ' Pull in all the items from the Master Sheet that are still scheduled or deployed.
    CurrentReportRow = 3
    TargetRow = 2
    Worksheets("RPT - Shelf Age").Columns(5).Interior.Color = xlNone
    Do Until Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(TargetRow, 1) = ""
      If Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(TargetRow, 37) = 1 Then
        Worksheets("RPT - Shelf Age").Cells(CurrentReportRow, 1) = TargetRow ' Transaction ID
        Worksheets("RPT - Shelf Age").Cells(CurrentReportRow, 2) = Left(Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(TargetRow, 4), 10) ' REQ
        Worksheets("RPT - Shelf Age").Cells(CurrentReportRow, 3) = Mid(Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(TargetRow, 4), 12, 11) ' RITM
        Worksheets("RPT - Shelf Age").Cells(CurrentReportRow, 4) = Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(TargetRow, 7) ' Depot timestamp
        Worksheets("RPT - Shelf Age").Cells(CurrentReportRow, 5) = Now - Worksheets("RPT - Shelf Age").Cells(CurrentReportRow, 4) ' Age in days
        If Worksheets("RPT - Shelf Age").Cells(CurrentReportRow, 5) > 3 Then ' if the item is older than 1 day, highlight the cell
          Worksheets("RPT - Shelf Age").Cells(CurrentReportRow, 5).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If
        CurrentReportRow = CurrentReportRow + 1
      End If
      TargetRow = TargetRow + 1
    Loop
    Worksheets("RPT - Shelf Age").Columns(4).NumberFormat = "mmm d, yyyy at h:mm AM/PM"
  ' Sort the table by that age -- oldest presenting first.
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    With Workbooks("Equipment_Transactions.xlsm").Sheets("RPT - Shelf Age")
      With .Range("a3").CurrentRegion
        .Sort key1:=.Cells(5), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
      End With
    End With
End Sub
```

edit (as of 28 May 2019):

Is there a cell-level function that I can inject that would satisfy this issue? For example, as I lay in the initial "removed from depot" row, I manually add a "1" flag to column AK, but maybe there's a cell-level command I can add that basically says "Make this cell self-calculate. If there is any other row on this sheet that has as its column D value the same value as this row's column D, and that matching row has "Scheduled" or "Deployed" in its column F, then this value should be empty, but otherwise, this cell should contain a 1."

Then I can just filter for all items where column AK contains 1 and I know that they've already been reconciled.

Edit (June 9, 2019):

A buddy of mine suggested “Why don’t you just shove all that table data into a big array, and then do your calculations and searches through the array. Only go back to the table when you want to change a cell value.”

People who know Excel VBA: is this a suggestion that would improve my speed a lot? Currently I have about 4500 rows of data, so that seems like a pretty big array to build. But if it’s hugely faster, maybe worth it...?

Hm, I am probably doing something wrong...

```
Dim SearchArray() As Variant
Dim GobbleRange As Range

      Set GobbleRange = Worksheets("MasterSheet").Range("D2:F10000") ' The top 10,000 rows, columns D, E, F
      ReDim SearchArray(3, 10000)
MsgBox ("Array built and re-dimmed.")
      SearchArray = Range(GobbleRange).Value2
MsgBox ("Array populated with contents of entire MasterSheet")
```

I receive a **Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed** highlighting the line "SearchArray = Range(GobbleRange).Value2"

Thoughts? Ideas? Suggestions?

Comment: "column D contains CANDIDATE_NUMBER"  - equals, or contains ?

Comment: Good catch, Tim -- I should have used "equals." I've edited the question appropriately.

Comment: _Is this a suggestion that would improve my speed a lot?_  **Yes**.  It's the most common solution to range loop speed issues, and will speed things up by orders of magnitude.  General pattern is: `Dim Dat As Variant` populate it in one go `Dat = SomeRange.Value2` do your work on the array, and if needed put it back on the sheet in one go `SomeRange.Value2 = Dat` (some variations on the theme may be required bepending on the nature of the resultant data)  there are lots of examples on SO - search for `Variant Array`

Comment: Chris, I must be doing something wrong. I added a little bit of code fragment to the end of my post. Can you advise how I can fix it? I'm sure I'm alllllmost there, it's just that this is the first time I have done this sort of thing in Excel VBA.

Comment: Basically I want to transfer the values from D2:F10000 into an array so I can then fiddle-de-hee in the array instead of slow-crawling all over the spreadsheet. And I guess I just haz teh dumz today.

Comment: Oh! Okay, I figured out the load-the-array part. Now to implement it into the search instead of searching through the sheet...

Comment: @EdwardMartinIII When you reply to a comment, please add `@Username` so they get notified.  Sounds like you sorted it, but for the record it's `SearchArray = GobbleRange.Value2`.  And there is no need to `ReDim` the array first (BTW that line was wrong anyway - if it _was_ needed it should have been `ReDim SearchArray(1 To 9999, 1 To 3)` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay!

First, thank you to everyone who helped me explore ideas. It all helped. Thank you to @Chris, who offered that last nudge in the right direction.

The solution turned out to be:

1. Throw the entire contents of the Master Table into an enormous array.
2. Do all my pattern-matching and hunting through the array.
3. If array operations tells me to change a value on the table (happens maybe 5-20 times per day), then make that change to the table.

The initial pass through the system took about 45 seconds. By shoveling all the data into an array and then pushing through that array instead of the table, I cut that down to maybe five seconds. I could trim it down even more, but honestly, five seconds to cycle through all the data is probably good enough!

Win!

Answer (score 0):

Use Autofilter to avoid loops and find your match(es), like so:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsMaster As Worksheet
    Dim wsRPT As Worksheet
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim aCandidateIDs As Variant
    Dim vID As Variant

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsMaster = wb.Worksheets("MasterSheet")
    Set wsRPT = wb.Worksheets("RPT - Shelf Age")

    With wsRPT.Range("D3", wsRPT.Cells(wsRPT.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
        If .Row < 3 Then Exit Sub   'No data
        If .Cells.Count = 1 Then
            ReDim aCandidateIDs(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
            aCandidateIDs(1, 1) = .Value
        Else
            aCandidateIDs = .Value
        End If
    End With

    With wsMaster.Range("D1:F" & wsMaster.Cells(wsMaster.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row)
        For Each vID In aCandidateIDs
            .AutoFilter 1, vID                                                  'Filter column D for the ID
            .AutoFilter 3, "Scheduled for Delivery", xlOr, "Equipment Deployed" 'Filter column F for the two other strings

            'Check if there are any results
            On Error Resume Next
            Set rFound = .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1)    'This assumes you only want the first match found.  For all matches, leave off the .Cells(1)
            On Error GoTo 0

            .AutoFilter 'Remove the filter

            If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                'Found a match, do something with it here
                'Because we only returned the first match, no need to iterate over rFound because it will only be 1 cell
                MsgBox "Candidate ID: " & vID & Chr(10) & "Match found on MasterSheet at row: " & rFound.Row
            End If
        Next vID
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I must have done something wrong, because that hung up so bad.

Comment: @EdwardMartinIII When I tested it, I populated the `MasterSheet` with over 150,000 rows of data, and it runs basically instantly for me.  Would need to see how you implemented this in your code to provide feedback.

Comment: I edited the original post to show the whole SUB, plus how I implemented your idea. Did i do it right?

Comment: Based on commenting things out, the first hang happens at the line ".AutoFilter 1,vID"

Comment: Hm, is AutoFilter 1, vID really filtering column D, or is it trying to filter column A?

Comment: Oh, the Autofilter is RELATIVE in the active range? If you are specifying that you are only working in the range D2 to Fx, then when you want to look at something in the D column, you specify that it is the first column in the named range. Does that help? Would it be the same as if you simply specified the whole sheet, and then looked in the D column?

Comment: @EdwardMartinIII Yes, the autofilter method is relative to the range object calling it, so because this range object starts at column D, column 1 = column D and column 3 = column F.  As for it still being slow, it occurred to me that autofilter does force a new calculation, so could turn off calculation at beginning of code and then re-enable it at end of code to see if that helps speed it up.

Comment: Hm, well, I tried turning calculations off and then back on at the end of the main looping, but the timing just wasn't that much better than my original cycling through. I must be doing something wrong, I dunno. Takes about 15-20 seconds to cycle through about 3300 items, and that's about how long my original looping takes. Sorry -- I must not be getting something.